# Windows crashes when hard drive is loaded

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ntfs

I have a hard drive which has 3 Windows installations on it, and it had 13 partitions in total. a couple days ago it stopped booting, it would hang on boot. When booting Windows 7 in safe mode it shows CLASSPNP.SYS and hangs. the status led flashes very shortly exactly every second.

I can read the hard drive on Mac OS perfectly fine, and booting into WinRE, everything crashes as soon as it tries to read one of the partitions. The status LED always does this 1 second flash thing, even if I plug the drive in as external (It just blue screened saying "DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE") but this is not super important. Windows PE can load the drive and shows the partitions in Explorer, but when trying to read two of the partitions it crashes Explorer. These are the two partitions I booted from before the issues occurred.

The day before the issues occurred I happened to make a full dd clone of the hard drive. I was able to use TestDisk which showed errors with most partitions to rebuild the entire partition table from scratch again using the offsets I found in the backup and all my partitions (except 2 small ones I didn't know existed so now there are 11 partitions). The partition table has no errors, so I tried the hard drive and it still crashes Explorer. Explorer does very very slowly load the partitions one by one and the data is readable but I can't execute chkdsk or do anything else because all other programs freeze and do nothing or just crash.

This made me suspect the boot record or master file table may be damaged. I used TestDisk to check MFT on all partitions and they are all fine. I used TestDisk for the boot records and every partition showed an error on the boot record, but TestDisk was able to fix it and now they don't have any errors on them. The data is accessible on Mac and it all works, but on Windows it still does not work.

Can I use dd to clone the image back onto the hard drive, but instead of waste time and unnecessary write cycles, interrupt dd after doing a couple GB so that the first part of the drive where likely the issues are is rewritten and the rest is untouched? I want a way to either fix the damaged partitions so that Windows doesn't crash when reading them, or I want to put back the data from the backup, but only the partition and filesystem databases, and not the files themselves since these are intact. Can I run chkdsk on the disk somehow even though chkdsk hangs like all other programs when I try to repair?

What can I do to find out what's wrong? The MBR, MFT and NTFS boot records are intact according to TestDisk on Mac, and I can't find anything wrong with the disk anymore. Is it possible to copy the boot record and file table from the dd image that was made a day prior? I do not want to rewrite the disk since all the data is still intact, I want to replace the broken parts but I don't know where on the disk the error is that causes Windows to have issues. It must be something only Windows needs on NTFS and I need some way to repair it. Does Windows log the errors when reading NTFS? What caused this, a cosmic ray or some write error? Perhaps malicious code? The hard drive is just fine and has not been dropped, it has operated for years without issues and I know hard drives die, but not like this. Is anyone an expert on disk forensics or does anyone know very very detailed how NTFS works and what can cause these symptoms?

Comment: This is why one large disk and Virtual Machine files is so much vastly easier and not breakable.

Comment: So you have a single disk, that crashes the entire machine, after attempting to read any partition even after restoring an image of the disk to the same disk itself. Replace the disk, restore the image to the new drive, and see if that solves the problem

Comment: @Ramhound It is one disk, Mac OS reads all partitions fine. Windows freezes the entire operating system after trying to read 2 of the 11 remaining partitions, the other partitions are fine. The cloned image still works fine.

Comment: Testdisk does not 'check' MFT, if compares if first few records are identical to the mirror.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you modernize your thinking and your approach.  I would find breakage and downtime like this intolerable in my work.

You can do all you are trying to do with Virtual Machines. I do this and have 4 machines running simultaneously 24x7, week after week, month after month, year after year, computer after computer.

I use VMware Workstation as best of breed and worth the small cost to acquire it.

Use a fast SSD as host and the VMs will be speedy.

Keep backups of the machines and you are further protected against breakage.

I have used partitions and dual boot years ago but found that to be slow and inefficient of my time.

Your time is worth money and any expense is quickly paid for.

What I am proposing is best for 90 to 95% of users.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it!
I spent 2 days of trying stuff, I rebuilt the entire partition table and repaired the NTFS boot records and nothing helped. The issue was not this, despite there being errors, the error was actually mostly caused by the MFT. I couldn't help but notice TestDisk said "MFT is identical to backup" and it didn't let me run scans to verify that the backup wasn't also corrupted.

What I did:
I got a ~500MB Windows PE image that I can boot from, it loads like the Windows installation iso files into the Windows PE environment onto a RAMdisk. It has tools for data recovery and other stuff, but what was most important, Explorer in this bootable image did not try loading the partition contents! I noticed that as soon as one program tries to load the corrupted partition contents the entire hard drive stopped being readable. Maybe it put stuff in queue but hard drive would stop all activity and refuse to respond, unless SOMETIMES Windows would attempt to load a different partition. This is probably Windows failing to error handle the damaged partition.

Since this light weight Windows thing didn't attempt to read the partitions, I was able to open cmd and run chkdsk <letter>: /f

To figure out which drives were damaged, all I had to do was open Explorer and attempt to open all partitions, and some of them crashed Explorer. I then ran chkdsk on these.
The reason chkdsk didn't work from regular Windows is that it tried reading the corrupted partitions and would just cause everything to freeze (wait for the partitions to be free to read but they were being occupied or something).

You just have to make sure not to run any programs that try reading the disk and immediately run chkdsk.

Steps to recreate:

- Unplug the hard drive with faulty partitions
- Boot from WinPE
- Open CMD and run MMC
- Add snap-in and choose device manager on local computer
- Plug in the hard drive as external hard drive
- Select the computer name in device manager (minint-xxxxxx)
- Click scan for new hardware
- Close MMC and open Explorer
- Check which partitions make explorer crash by opening them one by one
- Run chkdsk on these (or do all)

If this does not work, some other parition may be at fault.
If you boot into linux, either live boot or installed boot on which you can execute gparted, you can see which partitions are damaged since these have an orange warning triangle next to them. Deleting them from gparted for some reason makes the other partitions unreadable on Windows, so I suggest first deleting the damaged partitions from gparted, and then executing TestDisk from within Windows to restore the partitions (remember which ones were damaged and what their size was so you don't restore these again since you'll have to restart the process then). In my case it was some kind of recovery partition that was 400MB in size, after deleting it's unallocated and a new partition can be put in place (unless if the disk is physically damaged in this location). To recover data from the damaged partition, TestDisk can do this too.

Comment: you could have just deleted the partition and recreate it. if the goal was data recovery you're lucky chkdsk worked, and i wouldn't recommend anyone following your example.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I later actually figured out everything was caused by the first partition being damaged, either a bad sector on the hard drive, or some error in the filesystem, so I used TestDisk, and I manually set the offsets of all my partitions since I knew the offsets and had backups of it. You can also recover the offsets by scanning for partitions using TestDisk. I marked the first partition as deleted and all the other ones as primary partiitons and manually specified their filesystems. The data was never at risk, Windows just failed to error handle the damaged partition.